# disable input in some cells of asp.net grid view

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagridview

I've created a grid view with textbox to fill values in the textbox by the user. But the condition is to disable some of the cells textbox of the columns. Like

```
sn student_name eng_score math_score
1   jesna
2   norako
3   gjrusk
4   luma
```

the columns `eng_score` and `math_score` contains textbox for user data. But I've to disable `eng_score` for the `third row` and `math_score` for the `first row`. How can I do it?

I think I've to use `OnRowDataBound` method for it, but I do not know how to move further? How can I disable the cell [first row][forth column] and the cell [third row][first column]?

Comment: What does the GridView look like on the aspx page?

Comment: What does it mean by "What does the GridView look like on the aspx page?"

Comment: The markup of the GridVIew in on the aspx page? How is the GridView created?